# SED on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, sed, gnu, bsd

So I have tried to install gsed via macports but this hasnt solved the issue.  I was going to uninstall it to reduce clutter, however, before I do so, how would i fix the error below.  It is because of the BSD version of sed Mac OS X is running from what I understand, but none of the fixes I seem to have found are helping.

```
sed: 1: "/\[staging: production\ ...": command i expects \ followed by text

#!/bin/bash

test="lala\nkjdsh"
sed -i -e '/\[staging: production\]/ i '$test'' ./test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because of "\n" in the `$test`. Try to remove `\n` from it.

POSIX standard `sed` only accepts `\n` as part of a search pattern. OS X uses the FreeBSD `sed`, which is strictly POSIX compliant

So if you need a newline in a variable you need to write something like:

```
$ test="lala\
> kjdsh"
```

You can also solve the task with perl:

```
$ test="lala\nkjdsh"
$ perl -n -i -e 'print "'"$test"'\n" if /\[staging: production\]/; print;' ./test.txt
```

Example:

```
$ echo '[staging: production]' > /tmp/test.txt
$ test="lala\nkjdsh"
$ perl -n -i -e 'print "'"$test"'\n" if /\[staging: production\]/; print;' ./test.txt
$ cat ./test.txt
lala
kjdsh
[staging: production]
```

Comment: I need to preserve the new lines from the variable and add them to the script

Comment: I've just described the steps that you need to do when you want to add a newline with `sed`. Please check it.

Comment: `$test` is unquoted so it will be wordsplit after expansion, breaking the perl script into multiple arguments if it contains whitespace.

Comment: @geirha: you are not right, you can check it yourself, or just see my example (I've just added it). But if you suppose that there will be spaces in `test` you can add doublequotes around it.

Comment: @IgorChubin try with `test='foo bar\n"baz"'`

Comment: @geriha: I can only repeat myself: `But if you suppose that there will be spaces in test you can add doublequotes around it.`

Comment: Ok, so I had it working fine with simple text, but it has broken when I add something more complicated: https://gist.github.com/3342532

Comment: @user1570801, why do you put both literal newlines and `\n` in your variable?

Comment: just add `""` around `$text` in the `perl` line. I've just edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: Still having issues, I have tried changing the inout string, removing actual new lines, with no luck and adding "" around the variable.  I have also tried a few other methods: https://gist.github.com/3342532

Comment: that is a not very good idea to have your text in a shell variable and give it to the script using command. Because you have many symbols that are to be escaped in the text. Is there any file that contains the text?

Comment: not at the moment.  I have just discovered that would be better as I wouldnt have to be worried by special characters

Answer (score 1):

If the test variable does not contain a line containing only `.` you can use `ed` to edit the file:

```
printf '%s\n' '/\[staging: production\]/i' "$test" . w | ed -s ./test.txt
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed for more about `ed`.

EDIT: Oh and I missed that you actually had backslash-followed-by-N and not literal newlines in your variable. If you use literal newlines the above should work.

EDIT2: Given the pastebin given in the comments, try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#...
ed -s ./test.txt << EOF
/\[staging: production\]/i

; some comment
someStuffHere[] = "XYZ"
someMoreStuff[] = "$someShellVar"

; another comment
.
w
EOF
```

The `.` alone on a line ends the `i`nsert command, and `w` is the write command, which actually saves the changes to the file, (like `:w` in vim)